# Mock SSE Endpoind with WireMock in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, server-sent-events, wiremock

I tried to use rest client reactive to access the WireMock SSE endpoint.

```java
@Test
void getEvents() throws Throwable {
    var url = "/posts/events";
    String dataStream = """
            id:1
            event:random
            data:{"id":"test post 1", "createdAt":"2023-03-26T10:15:30"}
                                                 
            id:2
            event:random
            data:{"id":"test post 2", "createdAt":"2023-03-26T10:15:31"}
            
            """;
    stubFor(
            get(url)
                    .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("text/event-stream"))
                    .willReturn(okForContentType("text/event-stream", dataStream))
    );

    var events = VertxContextSupport.subscribeAndAwait(() ->
            client.events()
                    .onItem().invoke(c -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "item is: " + c))
                    .onFailure().invoke(error -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "error: " + error.getMessage()))
                    .collect().asList()
    );

    assertThat(events.get(0).id()).isEqualTo("test post 1");

    verify(
            getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(url))
                    .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("text/event-stream"))
    );
}
```

The `events` data in the decoded result is null.

```bash
2023-08-06 12:16:33,461 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.han.Con.__admin] (qtp1082618454-119) RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'
2023-08-06 12:16:34,055 ERROR [io.qua.ver.cor.run.VertxCoreRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Uncaught exception received by Vert.x: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Response could not be mapped to type class com.example.demo.PostCreated
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.ClientReaderInterceptorContextImpl.proceed(ClientReaderInterceptorContextImpl.java:131)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.ClientSerialisers.invokeClientReader(ClientSerialisers.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.InboundSseEventImpl.readData(InboundSseEventImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.InboundSseEventImpl.readData(InboundSseEventImpl.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.MultiInvoker.lambda$registerForSse$2(MultiInvoker.java:166)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.SseEventSourceImpl.fireEvent(SseEventSourceImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.SseParser.dispatchEvent(SseParser.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.SseParser.parseEvent(SseParser.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.SseParser.handle(SseParser.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.SseParser.handle(SseParser.java:11)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpEventHandler.handleChunk(HttpEventHandler.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleChunk(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:239)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection$StreamImpl.lambda$new$0(Http1xClientConnection.java:452)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:255)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.drain(InboundBuffer.java:242)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.lambda$fetch$0(InboundBuffer.java:295)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:246)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:43)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

And the RestClient Interface is the following.

```java
@GET
@Path("events")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@RestStreamElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Multi<PostCreated> events();
```

But in this issue https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/460, it seams it worked well in Spring.